# Change returned object in Java

Tags: java, reference, return-value

So I have the function

```
public Foo findVariable(Foo input)
```

that returns an object of type Foo. I want to take that object, and then modify it in `findVariable` in after it has been returned. I've read that you can't pass by reference in Java, so is it possible to have:

```
  public void func1() {
    Foo o = new Foo();
    Foo exp = findVariable(o);
    Foo newExp = new Foo(somethingDifferent);
    exp = newExp;
}
```

What I want is that the Foo object returned by findVariable is changed to the object newExp. Sorry if this is not possible, or is simple but I can't find it from the methods I've used searching. Thanks!

Comment: That would more-or-less work, aside from `somethingDifferent` not necessarily being defined, but I don't see the point. In the end, you're just overwriting `exp` with `newExp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mutate the `Foo` returned by `findVariable` in `func1`:

```
public void func1() {
    Foo o = new Foo();
    Foo exp = findVariable(o);
    exp.setSomething(different);
}
```

But if you do:

```
List<Foo> foosHandedOutByMe = ...
public Foo findVariable(Foo foo) {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    foosHandedOutByMe.add(f);
    return f;
}
```

and then call:

```
public void func1() {
    Foo o = new Foo();
    Foo exp = findVariable(o);
    Foo newFoo = new Foo(SomethingDifferent);
    exp = newFoo;
}
```

the `foosHandedOutByMe` list will not have the `newFoo` object.

Comment: So I just need a function for the object type Foo that takes an object to change to? I just can't use '='?